# Password int on Textfield - NO jQuery/CSS3/HTML5

Tags: javascript, passwords, textfield, onblur, onfocus

```
<input type="text" name="theName" value="password"
onblur="if(this.value == ''){ this.value = 'password'; this.style.color = '#333'; this.type="text";}"
onfocus="if(this.value == 'password'){ this.style.color = '#666';}"
onkeypress="if(this.value == 'password'){ this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000';this.type="password";}"
style="color:#BBB;" />
```

Like this, if the textfield is onfocus but not a thing is been written on it, the DefaultValue will be visible with a lighter color. (more like the facebook search bar)...
But id doesn't work... What did i write wrong?

Another thing that i don't get is that if i take this javascript and i put it into a  tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function passfocus(){
   if(this.value == 'password'){this.style.color = '#666';}}
function passblur(){
   if(this.value == 'password'){ this.style.color = '#666';}}
function passkey(){
   if(this.value == 'password'){
      this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000';this.type="password";}}
</script>
```

And i call this scripts in the textfield like this:

```
<input type="text" name="theName" value="password" onblur="passblur()"
onfocus="passfocus()" onkeypress="passkey()" style="color:#BBB;" />
```

Nothing works anymore... I think i kinda messed everything up!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use the `placeholder` HTML5 attribute?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Default value"/>
```

Comment: 'cause for what i know, not every browser or os support the HTML5 :\

Comment: Another possibility would be to have a simple <span> element containing your hint. When the box has text in it, show it, and hide it otherwise. This has the double advantage of being easily stylable, should you want to move your hint elsewhere. You can simply position the span over the box, or anywhere else.

Comment: Plus, the placeholder value is automatically deleted when you click on the textfield, and i already know how to do that without HTML5, i was trying to leave the default value also when you click on the textfield (with lighter color) untill you start typing.

Comment: Aaah!! the <span> might be a good solution!! :) i never worked with them, do you think they can do the trick?

Comment: I guess it depends on the browser. Chrome leaves the placeholder until you type. The solution in my second comment seems more sensible in that case.

Comment: @Andrea Of course! Put the span and the input in the same container. Give that container a relative position, and use position:absolute to place the span right over the text field. Use javascript to hide the span whenever there is text in the box.

As a side note, you might want to put your javascript in the header or in a separate file to make it reusable and easy to edit.